# SQL: Group rows by field a or field b

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am not sure this is possible in SQL. I have two fields "a" and "b" in my table. I want to group records in the table when rows have the same "a" values or the same "b" values and then extract a value of another field with the latest timestamp. Would this be possible? I am using Redshift.

Here is an example table:

```
|| key1 || key2 || date || value ||
| 1 | 'a' | '2019-01-01' | 'john' |
| 1 | 'b' | '2019-01-03' | 'ben' |
| 2 | 'c' | '2019-02-01' | 'kim' |
| 3 | 'c' | '2019-02-02' | 'dan' |
| 4 | 'd' | '2019-02-03' | 'jan' |
```

Eventually what I want to have is:

```
| 'ben' |
| 'dan' | 
| 'jan' |
```

Comment: How would you deal with the case where there was an overlap of matching `a` and `b` values?

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff for a great comment. I added some example data and my desired outcome.

Comment: thank you @Nick. My last desired outcome is what you were referring to? It is good to handle but not a must in my case

Comment: Clarification:  your results indicate that the following groups are created (john, ben - key1=1) (kim, dan - key2=c) (julia,dennis, mike - ??) why are julia and mike in the same group?  Would this record also be in the third group: ( | 5 | 'f' | '2019-03-04' | 'jim' | )?

Comment: @RichG I guess that's more confusing. 'julia' and 'dennis' are in the same group because of their key1. 'dennis' and 'mike' are in the same group because of their key2. I am hoping that these two groups can be merged. But that's not a must. Actually let me revise the question without the last case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to write a result set by `ROW_NUMBER` and `SUM` window function for those two keys.

Then get `rn = 1` latest row from the group.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT value 
FROM (
  SELECT value,
         sum(1) OVER(PARTITION BY key1 ORDER BY key1) cnt1,
         sum(1) OVER(PARTITION BY key2 ORDER BY key2) cnt2 ,
         ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY key1 ORDER BY date DESC) rn1,
         ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY key2 ORDER BY date DESC) rn2
  FROM T
) t1
WHERE 
   (rn1 = 1 and cnt1 > 1) 
or
   (rn2 = 1 and cnt2 > 1)
or 
   (cnt1 = 1 and cnt2 = 1)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a09d9/1/0)**:

```
| value |
|-------|
|   ben |
|   dan |
|   jan |
```

Comment: I missed one important case and added it to the example table (4 and "d"). Thanks!

Comment: @kee Ok just add `cnt1 = 1 and cnt2 = 1` for the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption:  date values are unique for all records.

I came up with this:

```
select mytable.value1
  from (select key1, max(date1) max_date1 from mytable group by key1) q1
  inner join (select key2, max(date1) max_date1 from mytable group by key2) q2
    on q2.max_date1 = q1.max_date1
  inner join mytable on mytable.date1 = q1.max_date1
```

Based on this schema:

```
create table myTable (
  key1 int,
  key2 nvarchar(1),
  date1 date,
  value1 nvarchar(20)
  );

insert into mytable values
  (1, 'a', '2019-01-01', 'john'),
  (1, 'b', '2019-01-03', 'ben'),
  (2, 'c', '2019-02-01', 'kim'),
  (3, 'c', '2019-02-02', 'dan');
```